# R Shiny: Force Shiny to throw an error instead of failing silently for nonexistent input/output names

Tags: r, shiny

Title pretty much says it all. I'm maintaining a nontrivially sized app, and I frequently forget what names I assigned to things. If I put the wrong name in, Shiny silently does absolutely nothing, which is harder or easier to find, at times. Is there a way to make the `$` operator behave normally, except for cases for which its second argument is not present, and throw an error?

I've tried using the `get` operator on inputs, but it universally fails, whether I make the item argument a string or not. I've also tried the following: it errors as I expect but returns NULL for every element that does exist.

```r
`$` = function(obj, item)
{
        if (is.list(obj) || is.reactivevalues(obj))
        {
                item = deparse(substitute(item))

                if (!(item %in% names(obj)))
                        stop(sprintf("%s has no member \"%s\"", deparse(obj), item))
                return(base::`$`(obj, item))
        }
        else
        {
                return(base::`$`(obj, item))
        }
}
```

Comment: Just an idea. You could compare a input to all inputs. If it is not in the input list, then throw error. Something like `if(!'MyInputName' %in% names(reactiveValuesToList(input))){ stop() }`. I did not test this method, but it is where i would start.

Comment: I tried something similar - edited with contents

Comment: Just to be clear. Is one of the requirements that this checks all inputs without calling any validation function ?

Comment: @brendbech I'm not sure exactly what you mean. To be more detailed - my ideal scenario is that I would be able to override `$` to error out if the value doesn't exist, without needing to make any further changes to my codebase, which currently uses `input$stuff` and `output$stuff` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`$` of `reactivevalues` is defined in S3 class. You can't just define "normal" function to do that. The correct way is as follow:

```r
library(shiny)
`$.reactivevalues` <- function(x, name) {
    if (!shiny:::hasCurrentContext()) {
        rlang::abort(c(
            paste0("Can't access reactive value '", name, "' outside of reactive consumer."),
            i = "Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?"
        ))
    }
    
    get_value <- .subset2(x, 'impl')$get(.subset2(x, 'ns')(name))
    if(is.null(get_value)) 
        stop(sprintf("Current reactiveValues \"%s\" has no member \"%s\"", gsub("\\(\\)", "", deparse(match.call()[2])), name))
    get_value
}
```

`deparse(obj)` is also not the correct way to get current object, I have fixed for you in code above.

We can do some test

```r
reactiveConsole(TRUE)
abc <- reactiveValues()
abc$a <- 123
abc$a 
# [1] 123
abc$b
# Error in `$.reactivevalues`(abc, b) : 
#  Current reactiveValues "abc" has no member "b"
```